# Multiple carts displayed when I click "Add to cart" many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following the guide from the book "Agile Web Development with Rails". Chap 11 "Add a Dash of Ajax".
I dont know why that when i click add to cart 3 times, there 3 carts displayed on the left sidebar, if i click 4 times, 4 cart displayed ...

i do not know where is this error.

*application.html.erb*

```
                <% if @cart %>
                <%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, :id => 'cart') do %>
                <%= render @cart %>
                <% end %>
               <% end %>
```

*store/index*

```
<%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product), 
:remote => true %>
```

_line_item.html.erb

```
<div class="cart_title">Your Cart</div>
<table>

<% for item in @cart.line_items %>

    <% if line_item == @current_item %>
    <tr id="current_item">
    <% else %>
    <tr>
    <% end %>
<tr>
<td><%= item.quantity %>&times;</td>
<td><%= item.product.title %></td>
<td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
<tr class="total_line">
<td colspan="2">Total</td>
<td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
</table>
<%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, :method => :get %>
<%= button_to 'Empy cart', @cart, :method => :delete,
:confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

_cart.html.erb

```
<%= render(cart.line_items) %>
```

/*--------Sidebar----------*/

Your Cart

1×  Book1   $10.00

1×  Book2   $10.00
Total   $20.00

Your Cart

1×  Book1   $10.00

1×  Book2   $10.00
Total   $20.00

Your Cart

1×  Book1   $10.00

1×  Book2   $10.00
Total   $20.00

**Home**

**Orders**

**Products**

**Users**

Comment: What's in your `app/views/line_items/create.js.erb`?

Comment: Finally i solved it.
Thanks to everybody.